# From old-school redirect-after-post to modern ajax form handling

Tags: javascript, forms, django, ajax

Up to now I mainly did old-school web form handling:

- redirect after post if the data is valid
- show the form again with errors if the data is not valid

I am searching a JS library which helps me to switch to ajax form submitting.

My needs:

- the server part should return html-fragements. This way I need to change only little on the server part.
- there needs to be protocol between the client and server part to do page updates after submitting the form data.
- The browser's URL should be updated without a page reload for GET requests (search results)

This library looks good, but it looks like a one-man-show:

https://github.com/eldarion/eldarion-ajax

Is there a wide-spread JS library which implements my needs?

The backend stuff is done with python and django. Returning the html-fragments according to the protocol of the framework is no problem for me. The JS and AJAX part is the topic if this question.